# Error with pred$fit using nls in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

So Im using nls in ggplot2 to plot a power curve code is below:

```
mass <- c(4120,4740,5550,5610,6520,6870,7080,8500,8960,10350,10480,10550,11450,11930,12180,13690,13760,13800,14050,14700,15340,15790,15990,17300,18460,18630,18650,20050,23270,24530,25030,27540,28370,33460,33930,34450,34500)

solv_acc <- c(2760,2990,2990,3180,3900,4010,4140,4680,4750,5330,4980,5860,5930,5570,5910,6790,6690,7020,6240,6620,6600,6860,7940,7600,8250,8530,7410,9160,9140,10300,10440,10390,11020,12640,11920,12110,12650)

df <- data.frame(Mass=log(mass),Solv=log(solv_acc))

plotter <- (ggplot(df, aes(x=Mass, y=Solv)) + geom_point(shape=1) + stat_smooth(method = "nls", formula = y~i*x^z, start=list(i=1,z=0.2)))
plotter <-  plotter + labs(x = "Mass kDa" ,y = "Solvent Accessibility")
print(plotter)
```

Running the above code I get the following error:

```
Error in pred$fit : $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors
```

I am assuming the error occurs when it tries to use `predict()`?

When I perform `nls` without the use of ggplot2 on the same data frame I do not get an error

```
> nls1=nls(Solv~i*Mass^z,start=list(i=1,z=0.2),data=df)
> predict(nls1)
 [1] 7.893393 7.997985 8.115253 8.123230 8.234519 8.273135 8.295350 8.429871 8.468550 8.574147 8.583270 8.588134 8.647895 8.677831 8.692939 8.777944 8.781648 8.783757 8.796793 8.829609
[21] 8.860502 8.881445 8.890558 8.947512 8.994380 9.000995 9.001769 9.053953 9.161073 9.198919 9.213390 9.281841 9.303083 9.420894 9.430834 9.441670 9.442703
```

Can anyone point out why I am getting the error?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Your question is answered in this [question](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2010-September/252780.html) on the ggplot2 mailing list. Briefly,

> According to the documentation for predict.nls, it is unable to create
>   standard errors for the predictions, so that has to be turned off in
>   the  stat_smooth call. .

So, we need to turn off the standard errors:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x=Mass, y=Solv)) +
  stat_smooth(method="nls", formula=y~i*x^z, se=FALSE, 
              start=list(i=1,z=0.2)) +
  geom_point(shape=1)
```

Update 2019: for new versions of ggplot2, we need the `start` argument to `nls` to be passed like this:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x = Mass, y = Solv)) +
  stat_smooth(method = "nls", 
              se = FALSE,
              method.args = list( 
                formula = y ~ i*x^z, 
                start = list(i=1, z=2)
              )) +
  geom_point()
```