# 'Method Args' for plotting 'nls' regression line with geom_smooth()-- Not working

Tags: r, ggplot2, nls

I am trying to overlay an nls object regression curve on a scatter plot in ggplot2, but I keep running into an error after various attempts in formatting the arguments. I have tried the following recommendation from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36745171/why-does-nls-function-not-work-in-ggplot2), but it does not work anymore since the version of ggplot2 was 2.0 at the time of that post, and is now 3.1.0 (at least the version I am using). Aside from using a previous version of the package, I am not understanding why this format is not working unless something has changed in ggplot2 that I cannot find documentation for. Thanks in advance!

```
ggplot(enzymes, aes(x=X,y=Y))+
  geom_point()+
  geom_smooth(method = 'nls', data = enzymes, se = FALSE,
              formula = Y~gamma_0*X/(gamma_1 + X),
              method.args = list(start = c(gamma_0 = 1/5.42, gamma_1 = 5.42/.49)))+
  labs(title = "Enzymes Nonlinear Regression Plot")
```

---

```
ggplot(enzymes, aes(x=X,y=Y))+
  geom_point()+
  geom_smooth(method = 'nls', se = FALSE,
              method.args = list(formula = Y~gamma_0*X/(gamma_1 + X), 
                                 start = list(gamma_0 = 1/5.42, gamma_1 = 5.42/.49)))+
  labs(title = "Enzymes Nonlinear Regression Plot")
```

#### Both give the following warning

```
Warning message:
Computation failed in `stat_smooth()`:
parameters without starting value in 'data': Y, X
```

#### Clearly, both have starting values...(unless I'm totally missing something)

Comment: use small x and y: `formula = y~gamma_0*x/(gamma_1 + x)`

Comment: If only you could see the dumbfounded look on my face regarding such an oversight. My first question was a doozy! Thanks! @user20650