# NLS Regression in GGPlot2, Plotting y=Ax^b Trendline Error

Tags: r, ggplot2, regression, nls, non-linear-regression

I'm attempting to fit a basic power trendline on a set of 3 data point, as you could do in Excel to mimic the y = Ax^b function.  I have a very simple data set loaded into LCurve.data as follows:

MDPT = {4, 10.9, 51.6}

AUC = {287069.4, 272986.0, 172426.1}

```
fm0 <- nls(log(LCurve.data$AUC) ~ log(a) + b * log(LCurve.data$MDPT), data = LCurve.data, start = list (a = 1, b =1))
  ggplot(LCurve.data, aes(x=MDPT, y = AUC)) + geom_line() +
    geom_point() +
    stat_smooth(method = 'nls', formula = y ~ a * x ^ b, method.args = list(
      start=c(a = coef(fm0)[1], b = coef (fm0)[2])))
```

For some reason this code produces the following error.

Warning: Computation failed in `stat_smooth()`:
singular gradient matrix at initial parameter estimates

The fm0 array has the correct values in the "a" and "b" fields, or coef(fm0)[1] and [2] respectively.  I confirmed that with a print of the variable.

I cannot figure out why I am unable to graph the NLS trendline in stat_smooth though.  Any ideas?  I've been googling for almost 2 hours now and keep running into dead ends.  Thanks!

Comment: I'm not getting the same messages as you, but I think you need `se = FALSE` for nls models in `stat_smooth()`.  And I think the starting values should be a list instead of a vector: `start=list(a = coef(fm0)[1], b = coef (fm0)[2]))`.

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25031125/2461552) shows the things I mentioned.

Comment: I added the se= FALSE flag and it doesn't make a difference.  The method.args code is coded properly, if you do start=list then it breaks.  I had referenced that answer previously to build my existing code.  Other ideas?

Comment: If I make those changes the code runs for me (although I thought the estimated line was pretty odd; it is only three points).  What version of ggplot2 are you using?

Comment: I'm using the newest version where you need to use method.args instead of start = ...  And yes, I'm only using 3 points to try and get the function working before I extrapolate to larger data sets.

Comment: I'm using R 3.5.1 and ggplot2 3.0.0, and the changes I mentioned allow `stat_smooth()` to work for me.  Hope you figure it out!