# geom_smooth does not appear on ggplot

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

I am working on some viscosity experiments and I'm trying to make an Eyring plot with ν vs. θ.
When I create the plot with `ggplot2` I can't get my model displayed.

These are the values used:

```
> theta
[1] 25 30 35 40 45
> nu
[1] 1.448462 1.362730 1.255161 1.167408 1.083005
```

Here I create the plot with my values from above:

```
plot <-
  ggplot()+
  geom_point(mapping = aes(theta, nu), colour = "#0072bd", size = 4, shape = 16)+
  theme_bw()+
  labs(
    x = expression(paste(theta,  " ", "[°C]")), 
    y = expression(paste("ln(", nu, ")", " ", "[mPa*s]")))+
  ylim(0, 10)+
  xlim(0, 100)
```

[That's what the plot looks like.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tTOyz.png)

Now, I add my model with `geom_smooth()`

```
plot +
  geom_smooth(
    method = "nls", 
    method.args = list(formula = nu~a*exp(b/theta), 
                       start=list(a=1, b=0.1)))
```

But nothing happens... Not even an error message and the plot looks just the same as before.

I also tried to put the `formula` directly as a `geom_smooth()` argument and the start values as well,

```
plot +
  geom_smooth(
    method = "nls",
    formula = nu~a*exp(b/theta),
    start=list(a=1, b=0.1))
```

but then I get the

> Error:Unknown parameter: start

Can anyone find the mistake I'm making?

Thanks in advance!

Cheers

**EDIT**

When separating the aesthetics mapping,

```
plot <-
  ggplot()+
  aes(theta, nu)+
  geom_point(colour = "#0072bd", size = 4, shape = 16)+
  theme_bw()+
  labs(
    x = expression(paste(theta,  " ", "[°C]")), 
    y = expression(paste("ln(", nu, ")", " ", "[mPa*s]")))+
  ylim(0, 10)+
  xlim(0, 100)
```

I get the following error (and still nothing changes):

Warning message:

> 1: In min(x) : no non-missing arguments to min; returning Inf
>   2: In max(x) : no non-missing arguments to min; returning -Inf
>   3: Computation failed in stat_smooth():
>   $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors

Comment: What happens when you try `nls` outside of ggplot?

Comment: @oshun
`nls` outside seems to work:

`> nls(nu~a*exp(b/theta), start=list(a=1, b=0.1))`

gives me the following:

`Nonlinear regression model
  model: nu ~ a * exp(b/theta)
   data: parent.frame()
      a       b 
 0.6153 22.7767 
 residual sum-of-squares: 0.008136

Number of iterations to convergence: 5 
Achieved convergence tolerance: 3.11e-06`

Comment: Put your aesthetics mapping separately instead of including it in `geom_point`, i.e. `ggplot()+aes(theta, nu)+geom_point(colour = "#0072bd", size = 4, shape = 16)+...`. Then you'll get your error message.

Comment: If I'm remembering correctly, I think `formula` in `geom_smooth` expects you to refer to x and y rather than the actual names of the variables

Comment: @lukeA thanks for the hint. See the edited post for the result.

Comment: If you don't insist on `geom_smooth`, maybe do `fit <- nls(formula = nu~a*exp(b/theta), data =  data.frame(theta, nu), start=list(a=1, b=0.1)); plot + geom_line(aes(theta, predict(fit)))`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have several things going on, many of which were pointed out in the comments.

Once you put your variables in a data.frame for `ggplot` and define you aesthetics either globally in `ggplot` or within each `geom`, the main thing going on is that the formula in `geom_smooth` expects you to refer to `y` and `x` instead of the variable names.  `geom_smooth` will use the variables you mapped to `y` and `x` in `aes`.

The other complication you will run into is outlined [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13840658/error-with-predfit-using-nls-in-ggplot2).  Because you don't get standard errors from `predict.nls`, you need to use `se = FALSE` in `geom_smooth`.

Here is what your `geom_smooth` code might look like:

```
geom_smooth(method = "nls", se = FALSE, 
              method.args = list(formula = y~a*exp(b/x), start=list(a=1, b=0.1)))
```

And here is the full code and plot.

```
ggplot(df, aes(theta, nu))+
    geom_point(colour = "#0072bd", size = 4, shape = 16)+
    geom_smooth(method = "nls", se = FALSE,
              method.args = list(formula = y~a*exp(b/x), start=list(a=1, b=0.1))) +
    theme_bw()+
    labs(
        x = expression(paste(theta,  " ", "[°C]")), 
        y = expression(paste("ln(", nu, ")", " ", "[mPa*s]")))+
    ylim(0, 10) +
    xlim(0, 100)
```

[image]
Note that `geom_smooth` won't fit outside the range of the dataset unless you use `fullrange = TRUE` instead of the default.  This may be pretty questionable if you only have 5 data points.

```
ggplot(df, aes(theta, nu))+
    geom_point(colour = "#0072bd", size = 4, shape = 16)+
    geom_smooth(method = "nls", se = FALSE, fullrange = TRUE,
              method.args = list(formula = y~a*exp(b/x), start=list(a=1, b=0.1))) +
    theme_bw()+
    labs(
        x = expression(paste(theta,  " ", "[°C]")), 
        y = expression(paste("ln(", nu, ")", " ", "[mPa*s]")))+
    ylim(0, 10) +
    xlim(0, 100)
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I just wrote this answer as @lukeA made the comment.

```
df<- data.frame(theta = c(25, 30, 35, 40, 45),
                nu = c( 1.448462, 1.362730, 1.255161, 1.167408, 1.083005))

myModel <- nls(nu~a*exp(b/theta), data=df, start=list(a=1, b=0.1))

myPredict <- expand.grid(theta = seq(5, 100, by =0.1))  
  #expand.grid here in case your model has more than one variable
  #Caution, extrapolating well beyond the data
myPredict$fit <- predict(myModel, newdata= myPredict) 


plot + geom_line(data = myPredict, aes(x= theta, y= fit))
```

[image]